# What is the difference between set cookie, res cookie and Cooki.set() (js-cookie)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, header, js-cookie

I am trying to implement an authentication system and I've run into some problems and after a lot of troubleshooting I've come to realise that I don't fully understand the difference between theese three:

```
res.cookie(name, value, [options])
```

and

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie')
```

and

```
Cookies.set(name, value, [options]) //js-cookie npm package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `res.cookie` (and `res.setHeader`) are coming from `express`.

[Documentation for res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie) states (just underneath the property table) that

> All res.cookie() does is set the HTTP Set-Cookie header with the options provided. Any option not specified defaults to the value stated in RFC 6265.

So, `res.cookie` is just a wrapper around `res.setHeader` to make the code clearer: you can pass options as an object, instead of manually constructing a header value.

Both of those are called on a `res` (a.k.a response) object, so it's a serverside tool to tell the client "please put that into cookies".

As for the last one, `Cookies.set`, that is intended to be run on the client instead. Internally, it just [sets](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/main/src/api.mjs#L46) the `document.cookie` propery.

So, if we build a tl;dr table of all mentioned cookie setting options, here they are:

| function | side | needs manual formatting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `res.cookie` | server | no |
| `res.setHeader` | server | yes |
| `Cookies.set` | client | no |
| `document.cookie =` | client | yes |